# jQuery related item table highlighter

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table fill with cell items.

If I click on a cell item, that cell item is 'linked' or related to other cell items, which need to be highlighted.

If another cell item is clicked, that cell's related cells need to light up.

Is there a jQuery plugin to accomplish something like this? Or would I have to look into writing one myself?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [jQuery UI Selectable plugin.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid)

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used Javascript that much, and only a couple of weeks behind me with JQuery.

Any tips on how I would manage theses lists for linking element items?

I'd use an onMouse event for trigger the UI Selectable?